# int to unsigned char array in Java

Tags: java, android, qt, types, casting

I'm trying to connect Android(Java) with Linux(Qt C++) using socket. After that I want to transfer length of message in bytes. For converting int in unsigned char array on the C++ side I use:

```
QByteArray IntToArray(qint32 source) 
{
    QByteArray tmp;
    QDataStream data(&temp, QIODevice::ReadWrite);
    data << source;
    return tmp;
}
```

But I don't know **how I can do the same converting on the Java side**, because Java hasn't unsigned types. I tried to use some examples but always got different results. So, I need Java method which returns this for `source` = 17:

`0x00`, `0x00`, `0x00`, `0x11`

I understand that it's a very simple question, but I'm new in Java so it's not clear to me.

**UPD:**

Java:

```
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
out.print(ByteBuffer.allocate(4).putInt(17).array());
```

Qt C++:

```
 QByteArray* buffer = new QByteArray();
 buffer->append(socket->readAll());
```

Output:

> `buffer` = `0x5b`, `0x42`, `0x40`, `0x61`, `0x39`, `0x65`, `0x31`,
>   `0x62`, `0x66`, `0x35`.

**UPD2:**

Java:

```
out.print(toBytes(17));
...
 byte[] toBytes(int i)
        {
            byte[] result = new byte[4];

            result[0] = (byte) (i >> 24);
            result[1] = (byte) (i >> 16);
            result[2] = (byte) (i >> 8);
            result[3] = (byte) (i /*>> 0*/);

            return result;
        }
```

Qt C++: same

Output:

> `buffer` = `0x5b`, `0x42`, `0x40`, `0x63`, `0x38`, `0x61`, `0x39`,
>   `0x33`, `0x38`, `0x33`.

**UPD3:**

Qt C++:

```
 QByteArray buffer = socket->readAll();
    for(int i = 0; i < buffer.length(); ++i){
        std::cout << buffer[i];
    }
    std::cout<<std::endl;
```

Output:

> [B@938a15c

Comment: You did not google for: java convert int to byte array.

Comment: @greenapps I googled that, at the very first time, but `byte` type has sign, so I get wrong result too

Comment: The sign does not matter with writing bytes to a stream. So show your code that goes wrong. Give an example. Dont tell that int source = 17; goes wrong.

Comment: A byte is a byte. It's not 'signed' until you start trying to do math with it (and who does that?).

Comment: @greenapps ok, please check UPD section of my question.

Comment: The output makes no sense. In no way. Show how you determined the hex values. Why do you think it has anything to do with sign?

Comment: Take the 'manual' function in the first stackoverflow post when you google for items in my first comment. toBytes(int i).

Comment: Show how you print those hex values please. The two outputs are not equal.

Comment: @greenapps please check UPD2. P.S. UPD - updated.

Comment: @greenapps I check them in the debugger window

Comment: You better log them or display them or encode them to int in your program. How is it possible that you have 10 hex values where only 4 bytes are sent? Makes no sense.

Comment: @greenapps no idea :) I will check it using log and cout...

Comment: Also do the reverse with sending four bytes from qt to android.

Comment: @greenapps as I said "UPD" equal to the "updated", I have seen this mark sometimes on the some forums and sites, including the StackOverflow, I think it comfortably to do these marks when we have conversation like this one. And please check UPD3 :)

Comment: `[B@938a15c` is the string representation of an object. `print` does not take a `byte[]`, it takes an object and gets the string representation on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, don't use `PrintWriter`.

Here's something to remember about Java I/O:

- Streams are for *bytes*, Readers/Writers are for *characters*.
- In Java, a character is *not* a byte.  Characters have an encoding associated with them, like UTF-8.  Bytes don't.

When you wrap a `Stream` in a `Reader` or a `Writer`, you are taking a byte stream and imposing a character encoding on that byte stream.  You don't want that here.

Just try this:

```
    OutputStream out = socket.getOutputStream();
    out.write(toBytes(17));
```